# What does it mean when a system boots into initramfs?

Tags: linux, boot, debian

I copied kali Linux 32 bit onto a USB stick using Win32Diskimager and Universal USB Installer.

On a Lenovo X200 it boots withoug problems. Both methods.
(P8400, 8 GB RAM, HDD)

Then I tried to boot on a Dell D430, it is not booting. I only get to a commandprompt showing "initramfs" where the "root@kali" would be in a terminal. But before boot, I cannot even get the different Runlevelterminals.
(Centrino Duo, 2 GB RAM, 60 GB HDD)
Laptop is strong enought to run Xubuntu, so Kali should run too.

Question:
What does it mean when a system boots into initramfs?

Answer (score 1):

initramfs is the state of loading the operating system into the RAM of the computer rather than continuing to read it from your removable media like USB or CD/DVD. It stands for "initial RAM file system", the linux Kernel mounts this area as the root file system and then launches the init process to start the rest of the fireworks.

Comment: it is like a terminal. where "user@hostname" normally would be there is "initramfs". What does this tell me? booting obviously failed.